# Making a 2 sided wedge shape

Tags: versions

I'm still very new to blender so sorry if this is a basic question, I'm trying to make like a 2 sided wedge, I'm not sure if that's what it's actually called though. I thought maybe I could do this with a cube and use a subdivision surface and then drag the edges down to make it slanted. To clarify what shape I mean, I will attempt to make one below

```
    _________________
   /                / \
  /                /   \
 /                /     \
/                /       \
```

Sorry about this very poor drawing/explanation, any help on this would be appreciated

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6283/how-to-create-an-equilateral-triangle-base-prism)

Comment: "Equilateral triangle base prism". Now that's a fancy word for a tent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a circle <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

Reduce its verts down to 3 >> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

<kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter edit mode

<kbd>F</kbd> to fill the vertices with a face.

<kbd>E</kbd> to extrude to the length that you desire.

[image]

Comment: note if you don't want one of the faces you can delete it in edit mode.

Comment: Or you could do the same with a cylinder and skip the extrusion.

Comment: @cegaton - Good point - more efficient